# Como validar uma data em um DataGridViewTextBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, winforms, validação, datagridview

Estou criando um formulário onde o usuário irá fazer a entrada de dados através de um `DataGridView`, uma das colunas desse `DataGridView` é do tipo `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` e ela irá receber uma data, gostaria de fazer a validação dessa data após o usuário digitá-la. Através [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15152532) no SOen, descobri o evento `EditingControlShowing`, então fiz o seguinte:

```
private void grdFeriados_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var controle = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
    // a coluna de index 0 é a coluna que receberá a data
    if (controle != null && ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        controle.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(controle_KeyPress);
        controle.Validating -= new CancelEventHandler(controle_Validating);

        controle.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(controle_KeyPress);
        controle.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(controle_Validating);
    }
}

private void controle_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && !e.KeyChar.Equals('/') && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void controle_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var controle = ((DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)sender);
    // ValidateUtils é uma classe estática utilizada para validação
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controle.Text) && !ValidateUtils.IsDate(controle.Text))
    {
        controle.Clear();
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Data inválida.", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

O evento `KeyPress` funciona perfeitamente, aceitando somente números, a barra e caracteres de controle, porém o evento `Validating` não funciona como esperado, pois assim que aparece a mensagem de erro e o usuário clica em OK, a data inválida volta para a célula e o foco vai para outra linha ou coluna, dependendo da tecla que foi pressionada (<kbd>ENTER</kbd> ou <kbd>TAB</kbd>).

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver esse problema ou tem outra sugestão de como fazer essa validação?

> **Nota:** tentei reproduzir esse caso em um novo projeto e o mesmo problema foi apresentado.

Comment: Só como sugestão tente usar o `dataGridView1_CellValidating`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ehy30d4(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Jota, esse link ajudou, combinei o `KeyPress` do `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` com o `CellValidating` do `DataGridView`, pode elaborar como resposta. Só achei estranho não funcionar o `Validating`, mas enfim, resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme sugestão do @Jota nos comentários, utilizei o evento `CellValidating` em conjunto com `KeyPress`, ficou assim:

```
private void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var controle = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
    if (controle != null)
    {
        controle.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(controle_KeyPress);
        if (((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            controle.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(controle_KeyPress);
        }
    }
}

private void controle_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && !e.KeyChar.Equals('/') && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void dataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)e.FormattedValue) && 
        !ValidateUtils.IsDate((string)e.FormattedValue))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Data inválida.", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

> **Nota:** a coluna zero é a que irá receber a data.

**Referência:**

[How to: Validate Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ehy30d4(v=vs.85).aspx)